# Show that if $f$ is Lebesgue integrable and $g$ is Lipschitz on $\mathbb R,$ then $g\circ f$ is Lebesgue integrable.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I need some help with following problem:

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a Lebesgue finite integrable function and $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a Lipschitz function. Show that $g\circ f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue finite integrable function.

Comment: Where are you stuck?  Please add your attempt, and where you get stuck, so we can know how to best help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: If $g$ is Lipschitz on $\mathbb R,$ then there exist $A,B>0$ such that $|g(x)| \le A + B|x|$ for all $x\in \mathbb R.$

Comment: And then $(g\circ f)(x)\leq A+B|f(x)| \Rightarrow \int (g\circ f)d\mu \leq \int (A+B|f(x)|)d\mu$ right?

Comment: Yes, basically, although you are missing some absolute values there. You also need to show $g\circ f$ is measurable.

Comment: Yes but it's true because $g(x)\leq |g(x)|$. Thanks for help, I didn't know that property of Lipschitz function.

Comment: @Matt53 "integrable" means $\int|g|<\infty.$   $g\le |g|$ doesn't tell you $g$ is integrable.